# Jail PHP to OpenBasedir or Document Root Debian

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian-squeeze, jail, open-basedir

I have a VServer running with Debian Squeeze Debian Squeeze / Apache2 / FastCGI / MySQL / Froxlor. The administration of Customers, Domains and FTP Accounts are performed using Froxlor.

Following problem:
If I install an application like Roundcube at the web space of an user, I need to set paths for the log file in the configs.
If I take the webroot as root directory, I will set "/mail/log/" as path to the log folder (based on the root of the web space), but PHP is taking this path and looks in the real system path under (/mail/log).
Now I get an "SAFE MODE Restriction in effect" Error

**-> Sure its has no rights to for this path in the Debian system.**

To resolve this I have to set the real system path to the log folder (/var/customers/webs/xxx/mail/log).

Is it possible to jail the PHP in the webroot (or openbasedir) that he think that the php root directory is the root directory of the user (/var/customers/webs/xxx/) using apache (vhosts, or php.ini). 
It would be much more easier to configure PHP application in that way.

---

**Update 09.11:**

As I figured out many people running multiple apache instances(each for one user) to solve this problem.
But there must be a more efficient way to jail PHP to the document root.

---

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks in Advance,
Fenton